# How to find the a destination of folder without having its full path using dos command?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

How to find the a destination of folder without having its full path?
I want to copy set of files in a folder to another folder.But i don't have the complete path of the destination folder, say `C:\temp\folder A` is the source
and the destination has the path as `D:\temp\folder X\folder A`

I dont know the  name of `"folder x"`, but I want all files of source `"folder A"` in `C:\ drive` to be copied to `"folder A"` in `"D:\ drive"`. I want to do it using DOS commands.

Comment: SO are you saying a folder with name "folder A" is already existing somewhere on D:? Why would you be willing to assume that it is unique? What if there are more folders with that name on D:?

Comment: Yes...i'm sure that there will only one folder named "folder A" inside "folder x" on D...but the problem is i don't knw the name of "folder x"

Comment: The Windows command line is not DOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

WScript.Echo FindFolder(fso.GetFolder("C:\temp"), "folder A")

Function FindFolder(parent, name)
  For Each sf In parent.SubFolders
    If LCase(sf.Name) = LCase(name) Then
      path = sf.Path
    Else
      path = FindFolder(sf, name)
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(path) Then Exit For
  Next
  FindFolder = path
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the drive letter, but not the exact folder. You could do a directory from the top level of the drive and then a find, which should return the folder you are wanting.

Dir /AD /s d:*folder A* /S

You should be able to use a for loop to parse through the output. The only difficulty in this is if there are multiple folders with the name "folder A" on drive D. That may be what @"Class Stacker" was referring to in do you need to assume it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a program for this, it can be done by a single command, replace the % with %% if used in a batchfile. In case you wonder: the "delims==" prvents the breaking up of "Folder A" in two strings, i tell the interpreter here to use the = as delimiter which isn't present so i get the whole sttring presenting the targetpath.

```
for /F "delims==" %a in ('Dir /AD /s /b d:\^|find "Folder A"') do copy "c:\temp\folder A" %a
```